# Setimage from the source of an item

Tags: android, setimagebitmap

I have a code with lots of imageview and I would like to dynamically change them on a click.
Do I really have to create a condition for every imageview clicked or can I do it simpler?
As an example, is there a way to do something like:

```
@override
public void onClick(View view) {
    view.setImageBitmap(null)
}
```

Comment: Do you want all of them to change their image on one click, or do you want them to individually change the images on a specific click pertaining to that image

Comment: You do not have to click one single image view. You could as well use a button for that. Or a menu item.

Comment: The code you have will remove the image but if you scroll and scroll back you will see that the image comes back.

Comment: The second solution. If that was the first, the solution would be much easier. The image I click must change it's image.

Comment: The setimagebitmap(null) is just an example for now. I will set to another image.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Further you did not react on the scrolling issue. Are the imageviews part of the items of a listview or recycleview?

Comment: None. It's just individual imageview I regrouped them in an array but they are individual.

Comment: You can assign that onClick listener to all imageviews.

Comment: I did. Now i'm trying to change the images on click

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you haven't yet, give `onClick` for all the images that you put

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image_1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />
```

Then in the activity you can make the Activity implement `View.OnClickListener()` and then define its `onClick` method as

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.image1:
                 //Do your thing
                 break;
            case R.id.image2:
                 //Do your thing
                 break;
            //Add all cases like this
               }
          }
```

Let me know if this was helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks but I'd prefere if I didn't have to use a switch. As I have a lot of imageviews, I'd have a lot of cases. Wouldn't there be a way to set the image directly in your opinion ?
Something like `int source = view.getId();
source.setImageBitmap(Null)`
Thanks for the awnser !

Comment: Thomas, did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564587/how-accessing-similar-name-variables-in-java) solve your problem.

Comment: Looks like it could ! I'll look at it and come back if I don't ubderstand ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found a quite simple way to  awnser my problem.
first, I put all imageviews in an array and get the id of these in another array.
Then I use Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(view.getId());

```
Pic[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Pic[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Pic[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
...

for (int i = 0; i < Pic.length; i++){
    id[i] = Pic[i].getId()
}
int u = Array.asList(id).indexOf(view.getId())
Pic[u].Setimagebitmap(null)
```