# how accessing similar name variables in java

Tags: java, android

i have 5 button as btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5 and a integer variable as numberInt

i want when numberInt changed to a number, button with that number becomes invisible
like this:

```
if (number == 1){
   btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else if (number == 2){
   btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

is there any way to use numberInt end of 'btn' keyword? because is hard to write if loops when buttons is too many.

Sorry for bad explaining.

Comment: Put the buttons in an array or list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the buttons in a list

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList();
buttons.add(btn1);
buttons.add(btn2);
```

then refer to them by index

```
buttons.get(number);
```

There is no way to construct an identifier at runtime e.g.

```
btn${number}.setVisibility(View.GONE); // not valid java
```

You can do that kind of thing in some scripting languages, but not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use 'If loop' if all your buttons are put in an array. Since arrays have 'int' as index that can be used to your advantage.

```
Button[] buttons = {btn0, btn1, btn2, ...};
```

use a method as below to update view's visibility

```
public void setInvisibleButton(int i){
   buttons[i].setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```